# Do social behavorial and economics (SBE) PhD students get funding in the US?

Tags: phd, funding, united-states, international-students

I am a Banking and Insurance graduate from India with 7.5 years of banking experience. I wish to pursue a combined MS and PhD in the SBE field. Do universities in the US fund such PhDs? By the way, I am on an H4 visa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, U.S. universities often fund these Ph.D. positions, though my sense is that there are fewer funded positions than in STEM fields. It would be very rare for a MS to be funded, as far as I know, and often opportunities for teaching assistantships (funding through teaching classes to (usually) undergraduates) are reserved for people in doctoral programs as opposed to master's programs.

Also, usually I hear these fields referred to as "social science," with the NSF being the only entity I associate with the term "SBE".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you point some "social science" disciplines that are more in demand than others? I was thinking about psychology.

Comment: @user65003 In the context of your question, I believe you should decide your field of study based on what you're most knowledgeable and passionate about, rather than what's in demand. Funded graduate study usually requires a lot of demonstrated potential for doing research in that specific field.

Comment: If I were to apply for a combined MS phd, would the intake for both of these be separate? Or acceptance to the MS equals acceptance to the phd program?

Comment: Acceptance to a master's program would almost never imply acceptance to the PhD program in U.S. social science programs I've heard about. (Usually you'd apply to the master's program, then afterwards apply to a lot of places for Ph.D. programs, or you would apply directly to a Ph.D. program, and potentially (maybe) get a related master's degree on the way to the Ph.D. For instance if you're in an Econ Ph.D. program, there may be an opportunity to get a Sociology Master's degree based on additional coursework.)